# App removed from Google Play store not showing Publishing status even after update. Any ideas?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing, google-play-console

My App was removed because I hadn't completed the Target audience and content section of the Play Console for my app.

[image]

Now, when I update the required fields and updated my app with new upload, it is still showing **Removed** in status instead of **Publishing**, which it shows whenever I upload a new version generally. Although, it is showing today's date **1 Mar 2020** as last update date.

[image]

Has anyone faced this?

Is it getting updated or it is removed forever?

What is the solution, please help?

Comment: noooo...I will lose downloads... it had 30K+ total downloads... :'(

Comment: There should be no need to upload new app. It clearly says in the mail that **This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.**

Comment: I recommend you to take a decision wisely As it is said Just follow the procedure and submit a complaint ...They will take care. Don't take quick decision in this...

Comment: @PraveenSP Ok. Let's be patient... I will wait and see what happens in 24 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App got Published. Status was showing wrong at that time.

[image]